# How to List up Favorite Tweets using Fabric SDK

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I have just gone through the [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android), and i am able to perform composing tweets and listing up some tweets in my app.
Now I want to list up all my favorite tweets.

I don't have any clue on how to implement that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to Fabric's TwitterKit.
You will want to use it to access [Twitter's REST api](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/api),
specifically the [`/favorites/list`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/favorites/list) endpoint